# UnboundLocalError- local variable referenced before assignment - Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

You guys have helped me out so much this week it has been awesome.Hopefully you can help me out with this one. I tried looking at the other posts on the site about this type of error, but none of them really helped me out. Basically I am submitting a form on one page and the POST data is going to the same view that it was generated with. I want to redirect to an other page after the POST data is sent, but I get this error.

```
def test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SubmitForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid():
            lat = form.cleaned_data['lat'] 
            lng = form.cleaned_data['lng']
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            story = form.cleaned_data['story']

            ctxt = {
                    'lat':lat,
                    'lng':lng,
                    'title':title,
                    'story':story,
                    }

            return render_to_response('home.html', ctxt, context_instance=RequestContext(request)) 

    else:

        import datetime
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        form = SubmitForm()
        latest_marks = Marker.objects.all().order_by('-submitted')[0:10]

        ctxt = {
                'marks':latest_marks,
                'now':now.date(),
                'form': form,
                }
    return render_to_response('test.html', ctxt, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The error I get is

```
local variable 'ctxt' referenced before assignment
```

And the traceback is

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/test/

Django Version: 1.3
Python Version: 2.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'userena',
 'guardian',
 'easy_thumbnails',
 'south',
 'database',
 'accounts',
 'socialregistration']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'userena.middleware.UserenaLocaleMiddleware',
 'socialregistration.middleware.FacebookMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/wluw/dev/chicagomap/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/wluw/dev/chicagomap/chicagomap/../chicagomap/database/views.py" in test
  58.     return render_to_response('test.html', ctxt, context_instance=RequestContext(request)) 

Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /test/
Exception Value: local variable 'ctxt' referenced before assignment
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is happening because `request.method == 'POST'` is True (first condition passes) but `form.is_valid()` is False (second nested condition fails), which means the final return after the else is run but ctxt is not defined.

Perhaps you intended that final return to be indented as a part of the `else` clause?

Comment: Alright. That makes sense. I just need to figure out why the form is not valid.

Comment: Put a `print form.errors` line after `form.is_valid()` to find out.